# How to document deconstructed parameters with JsDoc

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsdoc

How do I document a function parameter that gets deconstructed in function arguments?

```
/**
 * Function deconstructs argument and do stuff.
 * @param {} *** what should i do here? ***
 */
function someFunction({ key1, key2, key3 }) {
    // do function stuffs
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Document destructured function parameter in JSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916790/document-destructured-function-parameter-in-jsdoc)

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you @AncientSwordRage. will close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [@param wiki page](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties):

> If a parameter is destructured without an explicit name, you can give the object an appropriate one and document its properties.

> **Documenting a destructuring parameter**

```
/**
 * Assign the project to an employee.
 * @param {Object} employee - The employee who is responsible for the project.
 * @param {string} employee.name - The name of the employee.
 * @param {string} employee.department - The employee's department.
 */
Project.prototype.assign = function({ name, department }) {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: How do you document `function (arg1, arg2, { prop1, prop2 })`?

Comment: You  add `@param` tags for `arg1` and `arg2` before the one for the third argument.