# Document optional destructured function parameter in JSDoc, with vscode type checking

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

The question [Document destructured function parameter in JSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916790/document-destructured-function-parameter-in-jsdoc) hints at this, but doesn't explicitly ask about the optional parameter in the question. And also, I don't think they're using VSCode type checking?

I'm getting this error when [VSCode is type checking my JavaScript project](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) for me:

> (parameter) rejectMsg: string
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '`{ rejectMsg: string; windowSize: number; stallLimit: number; }`': rejectMsg, windowSize, stallLimit `ts(2739)`

The code in question is:

```js
/**
 * Function that wraps the on 'data' callback of a Stream, and monitors for 'stalling'.
 *
 * @param {(data)=>void} [successCb] callback run on successful chunk of data
 * @param {{rejectMsg: string, windowSize: number, stallLimit: number}} [param1] options
 * @returns {(data)=>void}
 */
const stallGuard = (successCb = () => { }, { rejectMsg = 'Stalled', windowSize = 5, stallLimit = windowSize } = {}) => {
  // code goes here
}
```

If I don't put the default param for those options (`= {}`) then it barfs when I call without any options passed in.

Is there a way of satisfying the type checking for this?